# Display all strings in a List

Tags: c#

I am trying to create two sets and put both in a list and display all items in the list. I am getting an error with my code. 
Error: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[System.String]]
I am attaching my code below. Any help is appreciated.

```
    namespace Prog 5
    {
        class Program
        {        
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<SortedSet<string>> items = new List<SortedSet<string>>();
        SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
        SortedSet<string> set2 = new SortedSet<string>();

        set.Add("a");
        set.Add("b");
        set.Add("d");
        set.Add("c");
        set2.Add("e");
        set2.Add("d");
        set2.Add("c");
        foreach (string item in set)
        {
            items.Add(set);
        }
        foreach (string item in set2)
        {
            items.Add(set2);
        }
        DisplayItem(items);

    }

    public static void DisplaySet(SortedSet<string> set)
    {

        string set1 = string.Join(",", set);
        Console.WriteLine(set1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DisplayItem(List<SortedSet<string>> items)
    {
        foreach (SortedSet<string> item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(items);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`SortedSet<string>` inherits from `Object` and the default behavior of ToString() is `GetType().ToString();`, because of that you receive `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet1[System.String]]` in the console. [**Reference Code**](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,d9262ceecc1719ab)

```
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

**SOLUTION:** If you want to show elements of the `SortedSet` in the console you should use this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", item.ToArray()));
```

This will concatenate all the strings in the `SortedSet` and show them in the console with `,` separator.

Answer (score 0):

In DisplayItem(...) you have Console.WriteLine(items)... which is type List>. ToString() automatically gets called on that to produce a string for Console.WriteLine to output: that's why you get your current message. I'm guessing you want to write each ***item*** to console.

```
public static void DisplayItem(List<SortedSet<string>> items)
{
    foreach (SortedSet<string> item in items)
    {
        DisplaySet(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements correctly, you are looking to merge 2 SortedSets into single list or perhaps set.

The following code should work (explanations of why it is working follow):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedSet<string> items = new SortedSet<string>();
        SortedSet<string> set = new SortedSet<string>();
        SortedSet<string> set2 = new SortedSet<string>();

        set.Add("a");
        set.Add("b");
        set.Add("d");
        set.Add("c");
        set2.Add("e");
        set2.Add("d");
        set2.Add("c");
        foreach (string item in set)
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
        foreach (string item in set2)
        {
            items.Add(item);
        }
        DisplayItem(items);

    }

    public static void DisplaySet(SortedSet<string> set)
    {

        string set1 = string.Join(",", set);
        Console.WriteLine(set1);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void DisplayItem(SortedSet<string> items)
    {
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The main issue in code listed in question is that it is attempting to create a List of `OrderedSet<string>` objects. Since each `OrderedSet<string>` represents a collection of strings you need to iterate over these collections and put strings into a new collection. The code presented in question does not do it. Instead of that it is adding 7 `OrderedSet<string>` objects into the List.

Corrected code fixes that issue and adds strings to a new `OrderedList<string>`. You can decide what collection it is depending on your requirements. If you need collection not to contain duplicates and be sorted you can choose a new `OrderedSet<string>`, however if you don't care about duplicates then you can choose a 
`List<string>`.

If you wish to compare the difference between `OrderedSet<string>` and `List<string>` you can simply change 'items' data type to `List<string>` and run the program.

Current output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

If you change

```
SortedSet<string> items = new SortedSet<string>();
```

to

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
...
public static void DisplayItem(List<string> items)
{
...
```

you will get:

```
a
b
c
d
c
d
e
```